# out of 2 hard disk only one is detected while reinstalling the windows 7 os in pc

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, operating-systems, reinstall

i am using windowos 7 os with 2 hard disk one hard disk is 256gb and another one is 1tb hard disk,after sometime i got some problem so thought of reinstalling the os,while reinstalling the os only one hard disk (i.e 256gb) is detected and not 1tb. please give me the solution to this without losing any data in both the hard disks.
Thank You

Note:- I am using 256gb hard disk since day 1 and then later i bought 1tb and
       started using both hard disks together.

Comment: could you please give us more details, is the 1TB drive internal or external? and when you said that is not detected, did you mean that is not detected during the installation process? or after it? also what models of hard drives you use?

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend you to unplug the secondary 1 TB HDD from the system while reinstalling Windows 7, @Abhishek. If you have more than 1 SATA drive connected to the motherboard at the time of the Windows installation, you risk encountering an OS confusion. This basically scatters the system files randomly across the SATA devices and would require you to reformat and start the process from scratch once again.

If you managed to avoid this and you have installed the OS successfully on the 256 GB SSD *(I assume)*, plug the 1 TB HDD back and you should be able to see all your files. 
Either way, make sure you backup your data from the drives somewhere off-site beforehand. Having multiple copies of it is what will save you from any potential data loss.

Hope this helps. Keep us posted if you have more questions. :)